# Error in formula that no longer exists

Tags: crystal-reports

*I'm using CR Professional - version 11.0.0.1282.*

When running a report through an external program I get the below error:

> Error in formula Font_Color:
>   `'if not isNull({InvItems_2.TYPE}) and {InvItems_2_TYPE} <> "fubar" then <br>16777215 else DefaultAttribute;'` 
>   A number is required here. 
>   Details: errorKind

The problem I'm having is that I believe this formatting formula no longer exists in the report.

Things I've tried:

- Checking every single formula in the Formula Workshop
- Exporting the report to Report Definition and scouring through every single line to no avail
- Saving as a new report and running it

**I have since deleted everything off the report and ran it with no errors. Am I at the point where I need to delete things one by one until I fix it or is there an easier way?**

[I searched prior to asking here and found this one user having similar issues with no solution on the SAP website.](https://answers.sap.com/questions/8290469/index.html).

---

### EDIT

By deleting fields one-by-one I've managed to locate the source of the problem, however the formula in question does not exist.

There is no conditional formatting in the font_color :

[image]

I've tried adding my own Font_Color formula for the field in question in hopes of overwriting the other formula with no results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answering my own question -**

To those of you who find this in the future, I could not find a solution capable of fixing the field that was causing errors.

*Just delete fields until it works, then replace the field that was causing errors.*

Good luck.